# UITableViewCell odd coloring issue:

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Why does this work:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

but *this* doesn't?

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250 green:100 blue:100 alpha:1];
}
```

Am I thus constrained to the pre-defined UIColor colours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250/255.0 green:100/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1];
```

They need to be float.

Answer (score 2):

The values you specify are invalid. Color channel values are floats in the range `0.0f..1.0f`.

Comment: thanks :) yeah, just need to divide by 255 then as ahmet implies. :)